# Phoenix 1.3 default generators // naive_datetime problems

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

Running `mix phx.gen.json Object Item items published_at:native_datetime` outputs the following files/tests :

Migration :

```
defmodule App.Repo.Migrations.CreateItems do
  use Ecto.Migration

  def change do
    create table(:items) do
      add :published_at, :naive_datetime
      timestamps()
    end

  end
end
```

Test fixture :

```
  @update_attrs %{ published_at: ~N[2011-05-18 15:01:01.000000] }
```

update assertion :

```
assert json_response(conn, 200)["data"] == %{
        "published_at" => ~N[2011-05-18 15:01:01.000000] }
```

And fails with the following :

```
code:  assert json_response(conn, 200)["data"] == %{"published_at" => ~N"2011-05-18 15:01:01.000000",}
left:  %{"published_at" => "2011-05-18T15:01:01.000000"}
right: %{"published_at" => ~N[2011-05-18 15:01:01.000000]}
```

Replacing the `~N[..]` values with plain "stringified" timestamps, tests are passing. What is the default change to apply in order to have it working with the defined column type ?

Comment: You are currently testing against the json response, and not the actual data type. You could directly execute a query instead...

Comment: humm i this understand, a json kv pair is always a string. But the example shown is generated with the default generator (`mix phx.gen.json Object Item items published_at:naive_datetime`); is there something to specify somewhere in the config in order to get a successful behaviour by default ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things:

1. `assert` [has it’s own handler](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/4a3bf4484d95deea6deb3ad87ba88b284c1873bf/lib/ex_unit/lib/ex_unit/assertions.ex#L101) for the match operator `=`, use it;
2. You should construct `NaiveDateTime` struct out of your string (or vice versa).

---

```
assert %{"published_at" => ~N[2011-05-18 15:01:01.000000]} =
       conn
       |> json_response(200)["data"]
       |> NaiveDateTime.from_iso8601!()
```

or

```
assert %{"published_at" => "2011-05-18T15:01:01.000000"} =
       json_response(conn, 200)["data"]
```

Comment: do you think they left this error appear on purpose in the generator ?

Comment: I am not sure I follow. How they could handle the comparison of a string against a struct?

Comment: Those tests are auto-generated from the command; I might be wrong but based on the field type, it sounds possible to generate a successful assertion

Comment: Incoming json response has a value as a string. How would you convert to the field type? What if it is `"2017/11/30"`?

Comment: All i have written in my question is auto generated; the command was `mix phx.gen.json Object Item items published_at:naive_datetime`; it knows that it is json, and that it's a datetime. makes me wonder why it's not handled then

Comment: Honestly, I do not see any reason for autogenerating tests that always pass. I believe this was made intentionally so that the developer follows TDD: red test ⇒ fix ⇒ green test. You’ve got there and now you know what issues to expect from date time passing via request params; otherwise you were to meet this issue in runtime.

Comment: ok thx! makes sense. as i'm getting in, could not be sure of not having done some wrong

Comment: @mudasowba would you mind looking at this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52243868/phoenix-testing-dates-in-controllers ? I think that was why i was asking  here; hope it makes more sense in the linked context