# phoenix / testing dates in controllers

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

Having the following basic test (using ex_machina) :

```
# factory
def item_factory do
  %Api.Content.Item{
    title: "Some title",
    content: "Some content",
    published_at: NaiveDateTime.utc_now
  }
end

# test
test "lists all items", %{conn: conn} do
  item = insert(:item)
  conn = get conn, item_path(conn, :index)
  assert json_response(conn, 200)["data"] == [
    %{
      "content" => item.content,
      "published_at" => item.published_at,
      "title" => item.title,
      "id" => item.id
    }
  ]
end
```

Am  getting an error on the date :

```
left: ... "published_at" => "2010-04-17T14:00:00.000000"
right: ... "published_at" => ~N[2010-04-17 14:00:00.000000]
```

Tried a simple string assertion with `"published_at" => "#{item.published_at}"`

But still failing with :

```
left: ..."published_at" => "2010-04-17T14:00:00.000000"
right: ..."published_at" => "2010-04-17 14:00:00.000000"
```

What would be the correct way to assert such case — how to correctly "cast" a date ?

Comment: Have you tried `NaiveDateTime.to_string(item.published_at)`?

Comment: @m3characters just did `NaiveDateTime.to_string(item.published_at)` in the assert response payload check, left is `"2018-09-09T11:23:21.896696"` and right remains `"2018-09-09 11:23:21.896696"`

Comment: Try `NaiveDateTime.to_iso8601(item.published_at)`.

Comment: there we go! and thx a lot. would you mind elaborating about what's happening in an answer ? I don't really understand the underliying of this all. anyhow; thx again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`item.published_at` is a `NaiveDateTime` struct. When it's converted to JSON, the encoder (likely `Poison` here) converts it to its ISO8601 string representation.

Your first attempt fails because you're comparing a `NaiveDateTime` struct to a `String`. The second one fails because the `String.Chars` implementation of `NaiveDateTime` uses a different representation than ISO8601.

The easiest way to fix this is to manually convert `published_at` to its ISO 8601 representation:

```
assert json_response(conn, 200)["data"] == [
  %{
    ...
    "published_at" => NaiveDateTime.to_iso8601(item.published_at),
    ...
  }
]
```